# AWS - False Billing Alert at 0.00 USD - at start of the Month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-billing

I have a billing Alarm set as Whenever charges for: `EstimatedCharges is: >=USD $100`
So i assume - The alarm should trigger when my Billing cost is above 100USD.

But early today i had a Billing Alert for my Alarm

That said

> *The alarm limit you set was $ 100.00 USD. Your total estimated charges accrued for this billing period are currently $ .00 USD as of
>   Saturday 01 December, 2018 11:24:23 UTC*

But when I checked CloudWatch the alarm state is OK

> State changed to OK at 2018/12/01. Reason: Threshold Crossed: 1 out of
>   the last 1 datapoints [0.0 (01/12/18 05:24:00)] was not greater than
>   or equal to the threshold (100.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for ALARM -> OK
>   transition).

Comment: What did you specify for INSUFFICIENT_DATA and when data is not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each alarm, you can set up 3 types of alert depending on the alarm state (`OK`, `ALARM`, `INSUFFICIANT_DATA`).

When you first create an alarm, its initial state is `INSUFFICIANT_DATA`. Then, depending on the metric value, threshold and period, it will reach the `OK` or `ALARM` state.

If you have set up notifications for all the different states, it's normal that you get a notification as well when the alarm went back from `ALARM` (end of a month over 100$) to `OK` state (new month - new bill).

If you don't want to get notifications when billing is under 100$, just remove the `OK` notification that you have set up:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, Got that had an Alarm set for OK state!  got this sorted !